# Having trouble installing virtualbox-6.1 on ubuntu bionic

Tags: virtualbox, dependencies

Fairly new to Linux and having a bit of trouble here...any help would be much appreciated. The specific package I have downloaded is: `virtualbox-6.1_6.1.6-137129_Ubuntu_bionic_amd64.deb`

After unpacking the package using the `sudo dpkg -i` command I have tried two different commands to no avail. First I tried running `sudo` apt install `virtualbox-6.1` which returns this:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
virtualbox-6.1 is already the newest version (6.1.6-137129~Ubuntu~bionic).
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 virtualbox-6.1 : Depends: libqt5opengl5 (>= 5.0.2) but it is not going to be installed
                  Depends: libqt5printsupport5 (>= 5.0.2) but it is not going to be installed
                  Depends: libqt5x11extras5 (>= 5.6.0) but it is not installable
                  Depends: libsdl1.2debian (>= 1.2.11) but it is not going to be installed
                  Recommends: libsdl-ttf2.0-0 but it is not installable
                  Recommends: gcc but it is not going to be installed
                  Recommends: make but it is not going to be installed or
                              build-essential but it is not going to be installed or
                              dpkg-dev but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

The other command I tried was running `virtualbox` which returns this:

```
WARNING: The vboxdrv kernel module is not loaded. Either there is no module
     available for the current kernel (4.18.0-15-generic) or it failed to
     load. Please recompile the kernel module and install it by

       sudo /sbin/vboxconfig

     You will not be able to start VMs until this problem is fixed.
/usr/lib/virtualbox/VirtualBox: error while loading shared libraries: libQt5PrintSupport.so.5: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

While it seems there are clues on how to fix the above i.e. I tried searching for the dependencies mentioned in my package manager with no success, and some quick google searches but am having trouble. I also tried browsing through The Linux Kernel Module Programming Guide but this seems pretty complex for a noob like me.

My assumption is I must be missing some basic steps here to do such a simple thing such as installing a program. Am I downloading the wrong package? Where can I find those 'dependencies'? Is there a command I am missing?

Thanks in advance,
HJ

Comment: `sudo dpkg -i command` is not "unpacking". It is the installation command. You don't need to do anything else. Also make sure that Secure Boot is disabled in BIOS.

Comment: Does it *need* to be Vbox 6.1? Can you use the perfectly-fine version 5.2 that's already in the Ubuntu 18.04 repositories?

Comment: user535733, Okay so it is the installation command but when I click on the application nothing happens i.e no interface pops up. Okay I will make sure Secure Boot is disabled and report back

Comment: And you have a wierd kernel version? Did you ever update the system? Ubuntu 18.04 should have 4.15 or 5.3.

Comment: Pilot6, No it does not need to be 6.1, glad to use any version that works. When you say Ubuntu 18.04 repositories--would this be the correct link for that? https://www.ubuntuupdates.org/ppa/virtualbox.org_contrib?dist=bionic

Comment: Pilot6, I have tried sudo apt update sudo get-apt update...I have been booting ubuntu from a USB stick, maybe that could that be the problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using

```
apt install -f
```

(-f to fix the installation)